# Can I use EF Core migrations when EF code is spread over multiple solutions?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, .net-6.0, entity-framework-core-migrations

I'm working on a program that is composed of multiple projects in two different solutions.

We're using dot net 6.0's EF Core as an ORM, but the database was not created using EF, nor the EF model was created from the database (Don't ask me why, it was before I've joined the team).

Anyways, As no one on the team has a lot of experience with EF (including myself), and our team leader wants to know if we can use EF migrations to keep track of database - here's my question to you:

How can we use migrations if our EF code (entities and `IEntityTypeConfiguration` implementations) are spread over multiple projects in two (or more) solutions?

Comment: In general yes. Just use the database first approach. Recreate your models, the context and initial snapshot out of the db. From that point on you could use migrations. The only risk I see is that you might have to refactor things after generating stuff out of the db. Put everything EF related (migrations and so on) into a new project (dll) and just link them with your existing projects.

Comment: You can have multiple DbContexts, each "owning" it's own set of entities.

Comment: you can create a common lib solution that can contain all the DAO class libraries that are required and then you can generate migrations from that.

Comment: The answer to the question is `no, you can't just use Ef migrations`. If you use SQL Server, use database projects at least. The problem is that ORM migrations in general are meant for relatively simple situations where the database schema matches the application models. They start to fail even with a single application if the model is too complex. In production, you may require different migration scripts than those generated by migrations to migrate existing data.

Comment: With any kind of ORM migrations you're controlling the schema indirectly. This can work if the mapping is simple. In your case, the two schemas don't match and therefore the mapping is *not* simple. Migrations are used essentially as a surrogate for explicit migration scripts. Database tools are far better at generating such scripts. If you already have those migration scripts, I suppose you could use EF migrations to execute them on startup and record their executions

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos unfortunately this project is a legacy and started out with NHibernate behind a repository pattern, later to be rewritten as EF Core behind that same pattern, but the guy that did the rewrite didn't have much experience with EF also, which brought us to where we stand now - any change with the database needs to be written twice - once in DB and once in code. Moreover, all existing entities are manipulated in OnModelCreating as well as in other projects in IEntityTypeConfiguration implementations. 
I would very much like to avoid a massive rewrite - Any other ideas?

Comment: Just two? That's pretty good. To get down to just one you'll have to decide whether the database schema comes first or the application. With complex databases, it's the database that comes first. EF migrations are just too coarse to allow a good database design. You can use Visual Studio or ADS Database Projects to version the database (if it's SQL Server). The database projects can be used to generate changes scripts. You can also use tools like those provided by Redgate to generate migration scripts from one DB version to the next. The EF model gets generated from the database

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos the database schema itself is pretty simple, it doesn't even have a lot of tables. It's the code that's a complete mess... I'm pretty sure migrations can handle the complexity of the database, its just the code that I'm struggling with. Thanks for your valuble input so far!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out the solution was stupidly simple, only had to read a lot and wait for the penny to drop - Here's what I've done at the end (currently as a POC, but I see no reason why it shouldn't work in the larger-scale actual project):

I've added a new dll project I've called Migrations to the solution that doesn't contain the `DbContext` class, added to it references of the project where the `DbContext` exists and references to all the other projects that have entities, and then created in that project a class that inherits the original `DbContext` of the project, and called it `MigrationsDbContext`.
From that point, All I've had to do was to load all the relevant assemblies from my solution in the constructor of the `MigrationsDbContext`, and simply run the migrations on that class as my DbContext.

The benefit is that I only need to change one static property in one class from `internal` to `protected internal` for it to work with the real code and that's it.
The downside is that I'll have to add a reference to every new project with new entities, but that's a really small price to pay for not having to re-write the entire mess.

Answer (score 1):

I recently did something similar when migrating from EF to EF Core. The process went something like this:

When data is split between solutions it will probably be easiest to manage by making them as independent as possible, i.e different database contexts, migrations, set of entities etc. We kept the data in the same database, but used different schemas for separation.

I'm not sure how well this will work if there is conceptually one database model shared between two solutions, but if that is the case you might want consider if that is a good idea. A 'Solution' implies a certain level of independence. I would probably also recommend keeping all of the database model, i.e. entities, migrations and context, to a single project.

You can create the database model from an existing database with the [Scaffold-DbContext](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/cli/powershell) command. This should give you a baseline to start migrations from. The applied migrations are stored in a special `__EFMigrationsHistory` table. To handle old databases we just added that table with the 'InitialCreate' migration by hand. There might be some better way to handle this, and I would be glad to hear it in that case.

Once you have a base line you can change your entities and create migrations with `Add-Migration`. While working you can redo the migration by deleting the migration-file, reverting the `dbContextModelSnapshot`-file, and redoing add-Migration. You need to be careful if you are working in branches since migrations should be sequential. When merging you might just want to revert all migrations in one branch and re-create them.

We also made a separate tool that can:

- Create the database(s)
- Apply any migrations
- Add default data to the database(s)

It is very nice to be able to recreate a default-database from scratch. If you get into some merge issue you might end up with a database that you cannot apply any migrations to. In that case it will probably be easiest to drop the database and recreate it using the correct sequence of migrations. You might also want some test-databases representing official releases so you can test that migrations work correctly for these, and make sure they contain some representative data.

Comment: I used some years ago exactly that way with an InitialCreate migration created out of an existing database.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. As I've stated in the question, I don't have a lot of experience with EF and therefor it's going to take some time for me to try it out (a lot to read and try before I'm confident enough to actually run it on the client's project).

Comment: @ZoharPeled I can't say I'm experienced either, but the only way to get experience is by doing. Just make sure you have a good test-process, and keep backups of any client data.